# Delete default "calendar" Office 365

Tags: office365, exchange-server

Is it possible to delete the default "calendar" for a mailbox or at least remove all the permissions for the user to use the calendar.

We work on a shared calendar but people keep putting things in the default calendar which isn't shared, and wonder why nobody turned upto the meeting they added...

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanism for that. However, if your users use Outlook on Windows, you may consider developing a COM add-in or just a VBA macro where you could handle such scenarios - detect where a new appointment is created and create a corresponding one in the shared calendar, or just notifying users about using the shared calendar instead.

The [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Calendar folder). For example, a VBA macro shows how to retrieve the shared calendar folder programmatically:

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```